# I have trouble increasing the QuantityOnHand for a Product using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

For some reason, the amt is null.  I am calling the ChangeStock method from the Products Controller and for some reason, it's saying that the amt is null.  I used a Viewbag in the controller method ChangeStock to store a ViewBag.

In the Product Controller, ChangeStock method I used the following:
`ViewBag.whatToChange = amt;`

On the Index of Products class:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeStock", "Products", FormMethod.Get))
            {
                <p>
                    Chnage By: @Html.TextBox("amt", ViewBag.whatToChange as string)
                    <input type="submit" value="amt" />
                </p>
            }
```

In other words, I have trouble using a textbox to call a controller's function. ChangeStock takes a product id and the amt as parameters.

For some reason, I do not know why when I click the button, it cannot call the ChangeStock method of the Products Controller.

Comment: I was able to get the amt on the URL, but I have trouble accessing the product's id.

Comment: In the URL, I typed in localhost:53459/Products/ChangeStock?id=1&amt=-10 and the ChangeStock method worked there.  I need help getting the textbox to work the same way as the URL did.  Like if I typed in -10, it should produce that same URL.

Answer (score 0):

Man there are some good MVC tutorial materials online. I highly recommend you read through some of them to get a better idea of how to construct forms in MVC.

Don't use `ViewBag` if you don't have to. You can define a class, i.e., `ViewModel` as container to transfer data back and forth.

```
namespace DL.SO.ProductChangeStock.Models.Product
{
    public class ChangeProductStockViewModel
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public double Amount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Use `HttpPost` instead of `HttpGet`. Maybe you have realized, when you use `HttpGet`, input values are appended to the URL. Also you need to declare the `ChangeProductStockViewModel` on the Razor view so that when you construct the form on the razor view, it's strongly typed.

Also you need to create hidden inputs for properties you want to go along when the form is submitted.

```
@model DL.SO.ProductChangeStock.Models.Product.ChangeProductStockViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Change Product Stock";
}

<h2>Change Product Stock</h2>
@using(Html.BeginForm("changeStock", "product", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <!-- Use HTML helper to construct hidden input for the id -->
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProductId)

    <!-- As well as the amount text box -->
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount)

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

Then create two actions inside `Product` controller, corresponding to the HttpGet (when the page loads) and HttpPost (when the form submits) request.

```
namespace DL.SO.ProductChangeStock.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ChangeStock()
        {
            // Initialization of the view model
            var vm = new ChangeProductStockViewModel
            {
                ProductId = 1,
                Amount = 2.3
            };
            return View(vm);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ChangeStock(ChangeProductStockViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Do your work

                // If succeed, redirect to somewhere else
                return RedirectToAction("index");
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something went wrong when changing the product stock.");

            // Redisplay the view
            //  You can always re-initialize the model data here too
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```